# Clarification on Interface concept

Tags: java, string, ant, static

```
interface A 
{
    public void printValue();
}

public class Test
{ 
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        A a1 = new A() { 
            public void printValue()
            {
                System.out.println("A");
            }
        };
        a1.printValue(); 
    }
}
```

We cannot create an instance of an interface, but what is `new A()` doing in this code? I have seen this type of code used mostly with Comparators. Please explain.

Comment: you can't instantiate interface.

Comment: @Rustam, that I have mentioned in the question itself. but what is happening in this code is my question.

Comment: You got the correct answer below, feel free to accept

Comment: It will create `Test$1.class` as anonymous class

Comment: that is annonymous implementation of interface `A`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new A() {}` is an instantiation of an anonymous class that implements interface A.

It is a short-cut that can be useful if you need an instance of a class that implements an interface only in one place, so you don't want to define a normal class. This way you define the class at the same place it is being used.

In your code sample, it doesn't seem very useful, but usually it is used by passing the anonymous class instance to some method that accepts a parameter of the type of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

new A() in below is where you are instantiating a concrete class (which we say anonymous) which implements the interface A

```
 A a1 = new A() { 
  public void printValue(){
  System.out.println("A");
  }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, interface A is used as an Anonymous class. You can use them if you need to use a local class only once. it's more over same as lambda expressions. 
Read more: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html
Read about lambda expression: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html